# Call function everytime after event/animation complete

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm using font face fix for IE, it using filter but every time I use jquery, jquery will replace the filter and font face fix will not working anymore. How do I call back the font face fix function every time any event or animation has been completed?

Font Face Fix URL : http://allcreatives.net/2009/12/05/jquery-plugin-ie-font-face-cleartype-fix/

Font Face Function :

```
(function(jQuery) {
    jQuery.fn.ieffembedfix = function() {

    // CONFIGURE THE PATH TO YOUR 1BY1 PNG HERE, RELATIVE TO THE LOCATION OF THIS JS FILE.

    var pngimgurl = "/images/hIEfix.png";

    return this.each(function() {
        if (jQuery.support.objectAll == false) {
            jQuery(this).css({
                filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=' + pngimgurl +     ',sizingMethod=crop)',
                zoom: '1'
            });
        }
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

I think it is ridiculous to add it 1 by 1, I use a lot of jquery event.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code? If you;re using a function that removes the filter then simply call the ieFFEmbedFix function below again at the end of whatever function that currently breaks it.
The code I use is slightly modified from the original. For me on IE8 the following bit of code was never returning false:

```
if (jQuery.support.objectAll == false) {
   // Not being hit
}
```

So this is what I use:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.ieFFEmbedFix = function(pathToPngImgUrl) {
        return this.each(function() {
            //Check for IE7/8
            if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 9 && $.browser.version > 6) {
                $(this).css({
                    filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=" + pathToPngImgUrl+ ",sizingMethod=crop',
                    zoom: '1'
                })
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

and then to call:

```
$('h1, h2, h3').ieFFEmbedFix('../images/hIEfix.png');
```